# PDFLib Centering an Image in a box

Tags: php, image, pdflib

I would like to center an Image both vertically and horizontally within a box using PDFLib and PHP.

I'm using the following code for this:

```
$p->fit_image($image, $xPos,$yPos,"boxsize={".$width." ".$height."} position={center center} fitmethod=clip showborder");
```

The image center that shows up in my generated pdf is somewhat off (by a few centimeters)
How does PDFLib calculate the center of the Image?

Comment: try to add dpi=72 option

Answer (score 0):

might it be possible, that you expect $xpos,$ypos should be the center of the image? The parameter x/y of the fit_image() are the reference point at the lower left corner. So at this (lower left) point the image will be placed regarding the boxsize, position and fitmethod.

I found the following in the PDFlib 9 API Reference, chapter 6.1 table 6.1 for boxsize:

> The lower left corner of the fitbox coincides with the reference point
>   (x, y)